# Why does symfony link_to helper append .php to application name

Tags: symfony1, routes

I have a symfony 1.4 application called `client` with a module `device`. Here is part of the `routing.yml` file used in this application:

```
device_detail:
  url: /device/:device_name
  param: { module: device, action: show }

device_manage:
  url: /manage/:device_name
  param: { module: device, action: manage }
```

I can load the page `http://example.com/client/device/jdoe` without a problem. This page contains links generated using the `link_to` helper. For example,

```
link_to("Manage this device",  "manage/{$device_name}")
```

generates the URL `http://example.com/client.php/manage/jdoe`.

My question is: why does the `link_to` helper generate a URL  containing the string `client.php` rather than simply `client`? It seems strange that the page address uses `client` but the`link_to` changes that to `client.php`.

Comment: Which version of symfony do you use?

Comment: I am using symfony 1.4. Updated question to reflect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your application's `settings.yml` file in `apps/<YOURAPP>/config/settings.yml` and adjust the `no_script_name` configuration flag accordingly for the respective environment.  Clear your cache afterwards.  Normally your dev mode would have `no_script_name` set to `false`, and your production would have it set to `true`.

Example:

```
prod:
  .settings:
    no_script_name: true

dev:
  .settings:
    no_script_name: false
```

**Edit**: As dxb points out, this is also only valid for a single application in your project.  If you have multiple apps in the same project you want this to apply to, you'll need to apply a prefix to routes (eg `/admin`), use a different domain/subdomain or similar solution.

Comment: Yes, hence my specific `apps/<YOURAPP>...` entry :-)

Comment: I tried the change to `settings.yml` you suggested. It *did* make the ".php" go away but it also had the effect of removing the application part of the URL entirely! With `no_script_name` set to `true` I get `/manage/jdoe`; with it set to `false` I get `/client.php/manage/jdoe`. So I have decided to go with `link_to("Manage this device",  "/client/manage/{$device_name}")`. This seems to be inconsistent with the suggestions in Chapter 9 of the symfony book, but this is the only way I could get it to work.

Comment: I don't see an inconsistency in Ch9. Rather, it lists 4 front controller files, and talks about configuring your web server to choose which front controller to use.  If your URLs for /client/* need to go to a different front controller, then you'll need to adjust via .htaccess and/or routing prefixes or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a parameter in settings.yml in order to remove the application name of your url.
prod:
  .settings
    no_script_name:  off

This works only for one app in your project.

Comment: I don't want to remove the application name from the URL, rather, I want to remove the ".php" portion.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have HTACCESS in place and mod_rewite enabled in Apache